# How to pass a form variable from one action to another action class in Struts 1.2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, struts, struts-1

How to pass a form variable from one action to another action?

Here is the example: (MyContractForm is in request scope)

```
MyContractForm.java
{
   private Calendar creationDate = Calendar.getInstance();
}
MyContractAction@method1
{
    myContractForm.setCreationDate(Calendar.getInstance());
    forward to myContract.Jsp
}
MyContract.JSP
{
   <script type="text/javascript">
   //For a button - javascript
   function getStatus()
   {
       document.myContractForm.dispatch.value = "method2";
       document.myContractForm.submit();
   }
   </script>
   <html:form>
       <button type="button" id="btnStatus" onclick="getStatus()">Get Status</button>
   </html:form>
}
MyContractAction@method2
{
    // should be able to access creationDate value that was set in method1
}
```

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `request` object to pass values across classes and JSPs in `struts`

method1:

```
request.setAttribute("attr","value");
```

method2:

```
Object obj=request.getAttribute("attr");
```

Comment: Can we put entire form in the request? request.setAttribute("myContractForm",myContractForm);

Comment: @Hello yes..you could set any data type in request since it accepets Object